# .attr() is not working in vml rendering

Tags: svg, vml

I am working in both IE8(vml) and IE9(svg). To retrieve a element fill color I have used the `.attr()` method as below

```
var value= $(element).attr("fill");
```

Its working fine in `svg` rendering , but in `vml` the value is `NAN`.

*Is there any other way to get the attr value in vml rendering?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In VML the attribute is called [fillcolor](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/vml/shape/examples/x_fillco.htm) i.e.

```
var value = $(element)[0].fillcolor
```